# How to get a specific file name from a path without the extensions python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the followint path:

```
f_file = /home/reads_dataset_1/E2_ER/E2_ER_exp1_L1.fastq.gz
```

And I'd like to get only the last file name without the 2 extensions:

```
E2_ER_exp1_L1
```

Tried:

```
sample_name = os.path.splitext(f_file)[0]
```

But I got the whole name of the path without the last extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

may be funny and dirty, but works :)

```
sample_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f_file))[0])[0]
```

also can use shorter, nicer version:

sample_name = os.path.basename(f_file).split('.')[0]

Comment: could just split  at . etc, but maybe this is easier to adopt to your current code :)

Comment: That gives me the whole path without the 2 extensions, and I want to get only the file name: E2_ER_exp1_L1. Is there a short way instead of using split?

Comment: os.path.basename gives you only file name

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but since `pathlib` was not mentioned:

Use `pathlib.Path`

```py
from pathlib import Path

f_file = "/home/reads_dataset_1/E2_ER/E2_ER_exp1_L1.fastq.gz"
f_path = Path(f_file)
sstem = None
# Repeatedly get the stem until no change
while sstem != f_path.stem:
    sstem = f_path.stem
    f_path = Path(sstem)

print(f_path.stem)
```

You'll get:

```
E2_ER_exp1_L1
```

Or if you know *exactly* that there will be two suffixes:

```py
from pathlib import Path

f_file = "/home/reads_dataset_1/E2_ER/E2_ER_exp1_L1.fastq.gz"
f_path = Path(f_file)
stem1 = f_path.stem
stem2 = Path(stem1).stem

print(stem2)
```